# deploy symfony 4 demo application on wamp

Tags: apache, wamp, symfony4

i installed symfony 4 demo application and it works perfectly with the build-in server but not with wamp.
i access to the homepage but scripts (css and js) are not loaded (404)
it seems to be a path problem : it try to load "localhost/build/..." and not "localhost/demo/build".
i tried to configure my apache as described here https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

but it doesn't change anything

my httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
    Virtual Hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName demo
    ServerAlias demo
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/demo/public"
    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/demo/public">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>

    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/demo/">
         Options FollowSymlinks
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You will need to include the relevant parts of your configuration in the question, we cannot _guess_ that.

Comment: Sorry, but please include all information in the question itself to keep it readable. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it!_

Comment: sorry, i edit my question,

Comment: I don't understand that configuration, sorry. You cannot have two hosts with the same name. Even if you _could_ configure that, what sense would that make? The configurations are in conflict.

Comment: Also, where and how is the variable `INSTALL_DIR` defined? I can't spot it in that file.

Comment: you' re right. I justt copy/paste the configuration on symfony documentation. I change the conf but nothing change

Comment: i don't know, it was already like that in my wamp when i downloaded it

Comment: Ah, sorry, just realize that you are on MS-Windows. There indeed you will run into many issues with such networking stuff, and that explains the `${INSTALL_DIR}` which is probably set by that executable. Due to the fact that MS-Windows still has no usable software management installations are pure anarchy, so no clear file system layout can be assumed. Which is why we see such issues all the time that don't occur on other systems. Sorry, that is not meant as a rant but as an attempt to summarize the situation you are in.

Comment: You should revise that configuration and use only a single host. Use the `ServerName` `localhost` for now, everything else only adds complexity for now. You do not need a `ServerAlias` for now.

Comment: Where did you install that demo application to, `C:/wamp64/www/demo/public` or `C:/wamp64/www/demo`?

Comment: in demo but in the symfony doc they use "/var/www/project/public"

Comment: thanks a lot!! it works. you're right it was because of the two host. i keep just one and go to "localhost" and it's good

Comment: Great to hear. You should try to understand that configuration a bit, what the different directives actually mean. The official documentation of the apache http server is of excellent quality, as typical for OpenSource software, and it comes with great examples. It will help you to understand the basic concepts behind such a server. Apart from that: good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to develop your Symfony application is to use Symfony Local Web Server.

However, when running the application in the production environment, you'll need to use a fully-featured web server. This article describes several ways to use Symfony with Apache or Nginx.

For your case, you will need to install apache Symfony pack.

The easiest way is to install the apache Symfony pack by executing the following command:

```
 composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

For more information, please refer to this article. https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html